# Cannot pass parameter from xml suite to test

Tags: maven, webdriver, testng

Im new to maven and testng
I got an issue: I cannot get parameter from suite xml file for my test when run Maven Test.
The result is this test is skipped:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: TestSuite
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.375 sec
```

I dont know why
Can anyone help me on this
I appreciate so much

Thank you

## This is my main test: hTest.java

```
package demo;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class hTest {

    @Parameters({"user"})
    @Test
    public void getUser(String user)
    {
        System.out.println("NAME= " + user);
    }

}
```

This is my suite hTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="hTest" verbose="3" parallel="false">
    <test name="hTest">
        <parameter name="user" value="Giao"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="demo.hTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BnS</name>

   <properties>
    <test.suite.dir>test.suites</test.suite.dir>        
   </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>           
            <configuration>  
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${test.suite.dir}/hTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using the maven [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) plugin rather than the surefire report plugin.

Comment: Hello, I change to maven surefire plugin and the result is:  `-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.8.2beta_20130330_0839 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

NAME= Hoang
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.274 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
`  THANK YOU SO MUCH :)